# Laravel Eloquent: API Resources - How does it work, so that I can create a similar class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent-resource

Look at this example:

```
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;

Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return new UserResource(User::findOrFail($id));
});
```

How does this internally work? Because at first glance we just return an Object of the class `UserResource`. But Laravel is magically calling the `toArray` function and resolves it correctly.

I want the same for my Recommendation class to work.

```
use App\Http\Recommendations\RecentlyUpdatedRecommendation;
use ...

Route::get('/someurl', function () {
    return ['collections' => [
       new RecentlyUpdatedRecommendation(),
       new WatchlistRecommendation(),
       new LastWatchedRecommendation(),
       ...
    ]];
});
```

With

```
/**
 * All Recommendations use this as output
 */
abstract class Recommendation
{
    // No Idea what needs to be put here
}
```

The output array/json should resolve into this:

```
    return [
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'courses' => (collection) $courses
    ];
```

Comment: And if you want to close this question, please explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any resource that you create is instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable` Interface,
This means that each of them **must** have `toResponse` method implemented.

If we look at `JsonResponse`'s `toResponse` method we see this code:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return (new ResourceResponse($this))->toResponse($request);
}
```

Internally it is calling `Resource`'s `resolve` method.

`resolve` method is where we see `toArray` method to be called

```
public function resolve($request = null)
{
    $data = $this->toArray(
        $request = $request ?: Container::getInstance()->make('request')
    );
}
```

By creating new response you are just overriding `toArray` method with your logic.

In Your case, you don't need to write too much to get `toArray` method "magically" called

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use JsonSerializable;

abstract class Recommendation implements Arrayable, JsonSerializable {
  
}
...
class SomeRecomendation extends Recommendation {

  public function jsonSerialize()
  {
    return $this->toArray();
  }

  public function toArray(){
    return [
      'title' => $title,
      'description' => $description,
      'courses' => (collection) $courses
    ];
  }
}
```

Now watch will happen, When you return `['collecion' => new SomeRecomendation()]`, Laravel calls `json_encode` on it ( to return response as json ),
Because `new SomeRecomendation()` is instance of `JsonSerializable` it will call `jsonSerialize` method and encodes an array returned from it.

When you return only `return new SomeRecomendation();` from controller, it will call, because it is instance of `Arrayable`, Laravel calls `toArray` method magically.

Hope this answer helps you.